# How to plot density plots with proportions on the y-axis?

Tags: r, plot

I am using the sm package in R to draw a density plot of several variables with different sample sizes, like this:

```
var1 <- density(vars1[,1]) 
var2 <- density(vars2[,1]) 
var3 <- density(vars3[,1]) 

pdf(file="density.pdf",width=8.5,height=8)
plot(var1,col="BLUE")  
par(new=T)
plot(var2,axes=FALSE,col="RED")  
par(new=T)
plot(var3,axes=FALSE,col="GREEN")  
dev.off()
```

The problem I'm having, is that I want the y-axis to show the proportions so I can compare the different variables with each other in a more meaningful way. The maxima of all three density plots are now exactly the same, and I'm pretty sure that they wouldn't be if the y-axis showed proportions. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Edit:

I just learned that I should not plot on top of an existing plot, so now the plotting part of the code looks like this:

```
pdf(file="density.pdf",width=8.5,height=8)
plot(var1,col="BLUE")  
lines(var2,col="RED")  
lines(var3,col="GREEN")  
dev.off()
```

The maxima of those lines however are now very much in line with the sample size differences. Is there a way to put the proportions on the y-axis for all three variables, so the area under the curve is equal for all three variables? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't plot on top of an existing plot, because they axes may be different. Instead, use `lines()` to plot the second and third densities after plotting the first. If necessary, adjust the `ylim` parameter in `plot()` so that they all fit.

An example for how sample size ought not matter:

```
    set.seed(1)
    D1 <- density(rnorm(1000))
    D2 <- density(rnorm(10000))
    D3 <- density(rnorm(100000))
    plot(D1$x,D1$y,type='l',col="red",ylim=c(0,.45))
    lines(D2$x,D2$y,lty=2,col="blue")
    lines(D3$x,D3$y,lty=3,col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped. But it still looks like the maxima of those lines are very much in line with the sample size differences. Is there a way to put the proportions on the y-axis for all three variables?

Comment: To make densities comparable, what you want is an equal area under the curve, not necessarily the same maxima. It's hard to tell if there's something else that needs to be taken into account without your data though. Can you post your data, a sample of it, or simulated data similar to yours? Then myself or someone else might take a look

Comment: I don't expect the maxima to be the same, but the large differences they show now are clearly due to the sample size differences. What I want is indeed an equal area under the curve... For the first variable I have about 100,000 observations, for the second about half of that, and for the third even less (the sample size differences are pretty large).

Comment: well, the sample size shouldn't make a difference: see example above. Are you being tricked by different x-ranges?

Comment: The x-ranges are pretty much the same. The y-axis now has values between 0 and 1200 (it looks like he's showing frequencies?), and I'm pretty sure the problem would be solved if I could transform those into proportions, so they would range between 0 and 1.

Comment: The value of a density function is not a proportion: 
it is not guaranteed to be between 0 and 1.
The area under the curve is 1, 
but if the density is very concentrated
(which is more likely to be visible if you have a lot of data),
the maximum can be very high.
Example: `curve(dbeta(x,1,100), xlim=c(-.1,1.1))`.

Comment: I think I found the problem... The plot looks good when I let the smoothing bandwith be equal between the variables using the "bw" parameter (see: http://127.0.0.1:28117/library/stats/html/density.html). Thanks a lot for your feedback guys!

Comment: However, I still would like to transform the density y-axis to proportions.. If someone has any idea on how to do this, I would very much appreciate it! :)

Comment: if you look at the increments in `density()$x`, they're probably less than 1, and that's how the curve can still get high. Assuming your 3 curves have the same x's, or at least the same x intervals (I'm guessing without your data...), you could divide each vector of y's by its own sum, giving you a pdf and forcing all values to be between 0 and 1. I don't know if that's good or bad form though.

Comment: hi @kputschko, the areas of the three densities in this answer are all 1 to the same degree of approximation, each derived from a different sample size, so the curves are comparable in the way requested. Also, the answer was accepted. What's missing?

Comment: Hey @timriffe, you are correct.  I'm not sure what I was getting at with my comment.  Perhaps it was a comment meant for another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could make tim's solution a little more flexible by not hard-coding in the limits.

```
plot(D1$x,D1$y,type='l',col="red",ylim=c(0, max(sapply(list(D1, D2, D3),
    function(x) {max(x$y)}))))
```

This would also cater for Vincent's point that the density functions are not necessarily constrained in their range.